# How to avoid changing database name when recompiling

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android programming, and I'm practicing with databases.

I've written an helper and a "DataManager" class.
But when I'm trying to execute my app on the AVD emulator, I always need to change my database's name, because I always get an error.

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DBstrings{

  public DBhelper(Context ctx){
    super(ctx,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String q = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key, "
            + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";
    db.execSQL(q);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

  }
```

What can I do to avoid this renaming every time?

Thank you. And sorry for my perfect english.

Comment: Please attach the error log.

Comment: Basically I have a SQLite Database that is initialized every time my app is opened. This initialization consists in automatically adding some entries in my db with INSERT queries. Every time I re-run my app, the queries are re-executed and obviously, I get an integrity error: UNIQUE constraint failed.

I want to find a way to erase completely my db and recreating it every time I re-run my app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the database name every time you compile the code. If you are modifying the database schema then you can just upgrade the database **version**. Share the error you are getting otherwise.

Comment: You can also uninstall and reinstall your app, if you're still in the developing/testing phase.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling my app does not delete the database file. So the UNIQUE error keeps showing.